# `WriteFile` error 1006 when writing to VirtualBox-redirected USB flash drive

Tags: c++, windows, io, usb-drive

I need to decompress an archive (`.zip`) file onto a USB stick, but after a successful number of `CreateFile()`/`WriteFile()` calls, I get various errors from `WriteFile()`, most of the time the first ones are `FILE INVALID` (`GetLastError()` gives error code 1006).

Please note that when starting the computer (I'm working on a Virtualized Windows 11) and launching the program for the first time, it works and fully decompress the archive. Any other attempt fails.

Here's the pseudo-code:

```cpp
// *dst is my usb stick mounpoint, most of the time its "E:"

static int decompress_file(const char * zip,
    const char * dst) {
    struct zip_stat sb;
    struct zip * za = zip_open(zip, ZIP_RDONLY, NULL);
    size_t readLen, totalLen = 0;
    char buffer[4096];

    for (long int i = 0; i < zip_get_num_entries(za, 0); i++) {
        zip_stat_index(za, i, 0, & sb);
        const std::string file = std::string(dst) + sb.name;
        struct zip_file * zf = zip_fopen_index(za, i, 0);
        HANDLE fd = CreateFile(
            file.c_str(),
            GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,
            NULL,
            CREATE_ALWAYS,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            NULL
        );

        totalLen = 0;
        while (totalLen != sb.size) {
            readLen = zip_fread(zf, buffer, 4096);
            WriteFile(fd, buffer, readLen, NULL, NULL);
            totalLen += readLen;
        }

        CloseHandle(fd);
        zip_fclose(zf);
    }
    zip_close(za);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to simplify the code, please note that it won't compile as-is. I'm using [libzip](https://libzip.org/documentation/).

The same code using `open()`/`write()` works fine on Linux/macOS.

This code is executed in a separate thread, the main thread is displaying a GUI (wxWidget) and waiting for this task to finish.

I tried to size my buffer according to a page size, 4096 bytes I guess for most of us? I also tried to set the buffer size to 512 and 8192 but It did not changed anything.

The error is always happening in the middle/end of the program's execution, after plenty of successful call to `CreateFile()`/`WriteFile()`.

I tried to monitor my program with [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer). I'm correctly closing the file descriptor, there are no red flags on Process Monitor except the one I'm describing to you.

Here's a capture of Proc Monitor's output :

[procmon output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8A7H.png)

I also get a `0x80000016` error, which according to MSDN relates to constant `STATUS_VERIFY_REQUIRED`:

> The media has changed and a verify operation is in progress so no reads or writes may be performed to the device, except those used in the verify operation.

https://winprotocoldoc.blob.core.windows.net/productionwindowsarchives/MS-FSCC/%5BMS-FSCC%5D-130808.pdf

I saw that a direct write to an external drive (when opened as a Physical drive with `\\\\.\` syntax) must be sector-aligned, but this is not my case here? I also tried to switch to `_open()`/`_write()`, but had the exact same issue.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: To make the code simpler, please try to abstract out the differences between the different operating systems into classes. Or use the standard library file streams which have already done that for you. Simpler code means it's easier to maintain and debug and fix problems.

Comment: Is it possible that your USB stick is counterfeit?

Comment: I edited my post according to your suggestion, thank you.

Comment: you said it's virtualized, how is it virtualized? how does the virtual machine access the USB stick?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude your comment seems irrelevant to the question... did you comment on the wrong question by mistake?

Comment: Two of us are getting the same error from different setup, ours USB keys are official lexar 1100 8GB/16GB. @Someprogrammerdude was right, I included both Windows and Unix version in my initial post, I edited my post since. I use virtualbox with guest additions to access USB keys.

Comment: the code seems okay; this is more like a driver problem or a virtualization problem

Comment: I added a procmon capture and only kept the minimal code related to the problem.

Comment: Are you checking for errors from `CreateFile`?

Comment: I do, I deleted error checking code in the snippet to keep things simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1006 is

> ERROR_FILE_INVALID
>
> 1006 (0x3EE)
>
> The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid.

"Externally altered" seems like a definite possibility when working with mapped drives (mapped from virtual machine host or from network server could both reasonably create that error).  It seems that the actual filesystem in control (running on the host) has removed the file, rendering your open handle stale and unusable.

Do you get better results if extracting to a virtual disk (VMDK) rather than a mapped drive?

Or if you give the VM control over the entire USB volume without having it mounted in the host?

Comment: The VM is hosted on VirtualBox, I installed guest addition and enabled USB 3.0 Controller(xHCI). The USB flash drive is only visible to the VM when it is running.

Comment: @voidboy: Can you at least try using a VDI file (a second one, separate from the one the guest booted from)?  If it works there but not with the VirtualBox USB redirection, it's a bug in the redirection.

Comment: @voidboy: Also check your guest's Windows Event Log for entries from the storage subsystem

Comment: I reinstalled the VM from scratch, I will try with a VDI to simulate a USB flash drive, thank you Ben Voigt.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Ben, I replaced the USB flash drive with a VDI(Virtual Disk Image). It successfully decompress the archive 3 times in a row. As I said earlier the same code works fine on Linux and macOS with `open()` and `write()`, but what I did not said is that Windows is the only operating system I used in a virtual machine, I tested both Linux and macOS on a native host.

To confirm that this is a "virtualization problem", I am going to install Windows 11 on a laptop and confirm this hypothesis. Thank you for your help.

EDIT: I tested my program on a native Windows 11 and it worked, I won't dive into why it failed inside a virtual machine, this solved my issue. Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to confirm that the problem is limited to VirtualBox's USB redirection.  I've updated your question title to include this important context.